# querySelectorAll in library

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
(function (window, document, undefined) {

  var g = function (sel) {

    return {

      selector: document.querySelector(sel),

      on: function (evt, fn) {
        if (this.selector) this.selector.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
        return this;
      }
    };
  };

  window.g = window._ = g;

})(this, document);
```

How do I use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` in this context, so that I can select multiple elements. Especially considering there will be multiple methods like `on`. How do I loop through all the elements and return them to the method it calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selector: document.querySelectorAll(sel),
on: function (evt, fn) {
    if (this.selector) {
        for (var i=0, len=this.selector.length; i < len; i++)
            this.selector[i].addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    return this;
}
```

If you have to re-use that loop in many methods, just create a wrapper, something like that

```
selector: document.querySelectorAll(sel),
forEach: function (codeToApply) {
    for (var i=0, len=this.selector.length; i < len; i++)
            codeToApply.call(this, this.selector[i]);
},
on: function (evt, fn) {
    if (this.selector) {
        this.forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
        }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Ok! I was hoping that I wouldn't have to create a loop in every method. Is there another way to create a loop in one place that calls the method for every element?

Comment: It depends on what are you gong to do in other methods. The way I suggested is the most general approach that allows you to run arbitrary manipulations with your selector nodes.

If you have a particular pattern in all your methods, this can be be used to optimized the wrapper code.